# Programmatically get index of a ViewController in the TabBar

Tags: ios, tabview

How do you programmatically get the index in the tab bar (starts at 0 for leftmost tab) of a view controller, from within the View Controller File.

I am switching views with this:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:nextIndex];
```

and I want to be able to just set:

```
int nextIndex = currentIndex++;
```

How do I get that Current Index?

EDIT: All three of the below answers are correct, thanks guys. To be fair I will choose the one that was posted first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get selected index:

```
NSUInteger selectedIndex = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
```

Get index of current ViewController (from within the VC):

```
NSUInteger selectedIndex = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
```

Set index:

```
NSUInteger nextIndex = selectedIndex + 1;
if(nextIndex < [self.tabBarController.viewControllers count])
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:nextIndex];
```

Comment: Excellent! Is either of the first two solutions better or safer than the other?

Comment: Depends on your use case: first one gives you the current selected index; second gives you the index of the (asking) view controller.

Comment: Ah thank you for the clarification. I will use the second one then.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current index of tabController with the property `selectedIndex`:

```
[self.tabBarController selectedIndex]
```

Also if you want get the index of a ViewController you can access to the array of the tabs with the property `viewControllers`.

Chech the Apple [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.